# Classic mass predictions from Left-Right models with discrete symmetries?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, research-level

I am covering the classic literature on predictions of Cabibbo angle or other relationships in the mass matrix. As you may remember, this research was a rage in the late seventies, after noticing that $\tan^2 \theta_c \approx m_d/m_s$. A typical paper of that age was Wilczek and Zee [Phys Lett 70B, p 418-420.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693%2877%2990403-8)

The technique was to use a $SU(2)_L \times SU(2)_R \times \dots $ model and set some discrete symmetry in the Right multiplets. Most papers got to predict the $\theta_c$ and some models with three generations or more (remember the third generation was a new insight in the mid-late seventies) were able to producte additional phases in relationship with the masses.

Now, what I am interested is on papers and models including also some prediction of mass relationships, alone, or cases where $\theta_c$ is fixed by the model and then some mass relationship follows.

A typical case here is [Harari-Haut-Weyers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693%2878%2990485-9) ([spires](http://slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/hep/www?j=PHLTA,B78,459)) It puts a symmetry structure such that the masses or up, down and strange are fixed to:

$m_u=0, {m_d\over m_s} = {2- \sqrt 3 \over 2 + \sqrt 3} $

Of course in such case $\theta_c$ is fixed to 15 degrees. But also $m_u=0$, which is an extra prediction even if the fixing of Cabibbo angle were ad-hoc.

Ok, so my question is, are there other models in this theme containing predictions for quark masses? Or was Harari et al. an exception until the arrival of Koide models?

Comment: Also, published criticisms of these papers are welcome. I am aware of some for Harari et al.